# Add numbering column in MUI data table

Tags: reactjs, datatable, material-ui

i would like to add numbering column that would maybe display the row index, So row one would have the number one and so on...Everything in the data table displays fine except for the numbering. But I haven't been able to find a solution to do it.
here is my code

I added this action column with buttons

```
const actionColumn = [
{
  field: "action",
  headerName: "Action",
  width: 200,
  renderCell: (params) => {
    return (
      <div className="cellAction">
        <Link to={`${params.row._id}`} style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
          <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" size="small" >Details</Button>
        </Link>
        <div
          className="deleteButton"
          onClick={() => console.log(params.row._id)}
        >
         <div className="deleteButton">
          <DeleteOutlinedIcon sx={{color:'red'}} fontSize='small'/>
          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  },
},
 ];
```

This is the column I would like to add.it should show numbering.As seen i have tried using customBodyRender but to avail

```
     const numbering=[{
    name: '#',
    options: {
        filter: false,
        customBodyRender: ( value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
            return (
              tableMeta.rowIndex + 1
            );
        }
       }
      }
     ]
  const concat =employeeColumns.concat(actionColumn)
```

Employees column above is from another file and it works well..I just would like to know how to do the numbering of each row so i can keep count of items in the datatable
this is my jsx

```
  return (
<div className="datatable">
  <DataGrid
    rows={data}
    className="datagrid"
    getRowId={(data)=>data._id}
    checkboxSelection
    columns={concat}
    pageSize={9}
    count
    rowsPerPageOptions={[9]}
    components={{ Toolbar: GridToolbar }}
    componentsProps={{
      toolbar: {
        showQuickFilter: true,
        quickFilterProps: { debounceMs: 500 },
      },
    }}
    initialState={{
      filter: {
        filterModel: {
          items: [],
          quickFilterLogicOperator: GridLinkOperator.Or,
        },
      },
    }}
  />
</div>
);
};
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The MUI Table requires a column with a unique identifier. So you're better off just adding/updating an existing property when you need it:

```
<DataGrid rows={rows.map((item, idx) => ({ id: idx + 1, ...item }))} .../>
```

Or ahead of time in recoil/redux or some local state-

[How to auto increment row id when inserting new row in MUI Data Grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75213694/how-to-auto-increment-row-id-when-inserting-new-row-in-mui-data-grid)